# How to prevent/protect my rights to content I write (US)

Tags: united-states, copyright

I live in the US and do writing of my own in various forms ranging from blog posts to content for handouts and trainings I might want to resell at some point in the future.

What steps I should take to legally protect the content I write so that it isn't taken and sold elsewhere later on? Are there additional things I should be thinking about before, during and after writing this content?

Answer (score 6):

Internationally, according to the Berne Convention, "copyrights for creative works are automatically in force upon their creation without being asserted or declared" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention)). However, in the United States, you can register your work with the [US Copyright Office](http://www.copyright.gov/eco/) to receive [additional protection and benefits](http://www.sfwa.org/2013/02/the-benefits-of-copyright-registration/), such as (if you promptly register) being granted statutory damages and attorney’s fees in case of infringement.